# AWS ALB Listener Rules - OIDC - Google Oauth

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-oauth, openid-connect, amazon-elb

I am trying to set Listener rules on an ALB. I want to add Google Oauth support to one of my servers.

Here are the Google endpoints I am using [image]

I see google auth page alright, but on the callback url I'm seeing 500 Internal Server Error. I've also set the callback URL. Am at a loss as to what's wrong here. Any help is most appreciated!

After authentication, I'm not redirecting to my application, instead I've set ALP to show a text based simple response.

Comment: Error 500 means that your code on the webserver crashed. Look in the server logfiles for what happened.

Comment: No, it's an ELB level error. I am not calling any code on server side, Ive set the ELB to show a simple response once the authentication is done. The error is coming during authentication step.

Comment: How have you verified that it is an ELB error? Pleae post the contents of the ELB logfile for this error.

Comment: The logs don't show anything, but I don't have anything setup on the server. The ALB is failing on "/oauth2/idpresponse" url which, I believe, is oauth related. For Google I'm seeing 500 while for onelogin I'm seeing 561. :(

Comment: Check your security group for the ALB - you need an outgoing rule for port 443 to allow it to contact your auth provider.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for hours, and in the end it turned out to be the user info endpoint that was wrong. I was using the same one as you, but it should be `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo`.

I haven’t found any Google documentation saying what the value should be, but found this excellent blog post that contained a working example: https://cloudonaut.io/how-to-secure-your-devops-tools-with-alb-authentication/ (the first example uses Cognito, but the second uses OIDC and Google directly).

Answer (score -1):

From AWS documentation

> HTTP 500: Internal Server Error
>   Possible causes:

You configured an AWS WAF web access control list (web ACL) and there was an error executing the web ACL rules.

You configured a listener rule to authenticate users, but one of the following is true:

The load balancer is unable to communicate with the IdP token endpoint or the IdP user info endpoint. Verify that the security groups for your load balancer and the network ACLs for your VPC allow outbound access to these endpoints. Verify that your VPC has internet access. If you have an internal-facing load balancer, use a NAT gateway to enable internet access.

The size of the claims returned by the IdP exceeded the maximum size supported by the load balancer.

A client submitted an HTTP/1.0 request without a host header, and the load balancer was unable to generate a redirect URL.

A client submitted a request without an HTTP protocol, and the load balancer was unable to generate a redirect URL.

The requested scope doesn't return an ID token.